# When creating a CSV file, do you need to escape certain characters?

Tags: mysql, ruby, csv

I am generating a CSV file from Ruby. The problem is a column string will contain double quotes, single quotes. How can I escape these things?

```
"Mary had a little so called \"lamb\"","34","none"
"something is not \"right\"","23","none"
```

Each column is enclosed in double quotes followed by comma (and no space), and written into a file.

Additionally, how do you insert CSV into MySQL? Would you need to use something like PHP's mysql_real_escape_string?

Comment: Yes, you need to quote strings containing commas or quotes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Writing CSV data is easy, the simplest way is to replace every instance of a double quote with 2 double quotes and then surround the whole thing in double quotes.  Alternatively, if your data does not contain double quotes, commas, carriage returns, linefeeds, or leading/trailing space, you don't have to surround the data with quotes or worry about escaping.  You can find more information [here](http://www.creativyst.com/Doc/Articles/CSV/CSV01.htm).

Parsing CSV is much more complex, especially if you try to handle various forms of malformed data out there, in this case you almost certainly want to use an existing module.

Comment: Hmmm, this doesn't appear to be true (or at least, not true anymore.) I created a CSV file with a field that had the value `"=1+1"`.... and then imported this into Google Sheets. It displays a `2`. It completely ignored the surrounding quotes and treated the string as a expression! So it does seem that `=` needs to be escaped. I've read elsewhere that `+` and `-` should also be escaped, as some spreadsheet programs try to be "smart" and execute strings that look like expressions.

Answer (score 2):

Use FasterCSV.  Do not roll your own CSV generation.

http://fastercsv.rubyforge.org/

Comment: Unless he is looking for something very specific that FasterCSV doesn't have.

Comment: Agreed, however I find that unlikely.  

The advice "use the library, do not roll your own" is a cliche, but it is a cliche for a reason.  The vast majority of the time, it's the correct advice.